# Running surefire concurrently with shared resources between tests

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project with many integration tests that and I'm trying to reduce the tests execution time.
The tests are all JUnit tests that use a DB connection. 
Currently all tests run one by one using maven-surefire-plugin with fork for each test in order to handle cache issues (The caches here are not the issue).

All tests use an app that persist to the same DB schema. This face a challenge when trying to parallel the process.

I found a nice blog that explain a bit about concurrency in surefire http://incodewetrustinc.blogspot.com/2010/01/run-your-junit-tests-concurrently-with.html
but I still have a problem implementing this solution since I have a shared resource.

My idea was to create multiple schemas and share them between threads \ process. How can I assign each test with a separate connection and avoid collisions ?

I would love to hear some ideas.

Thanks,
Ika.

Answer (score 0):

Use `${surefire.forkNumber}` as part of your DB connection ID. Then each thread running tests will use a separate connection.